# Counting values in array returning empty

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that when printed using `print_r($user_ids);` outputs as:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 2 ) )
```

I have tried writing the following where I am trying to count how many user_ids there are, so this should print 1 but it is printing as if the array is emptry

```
print_r(array_count_values($user_ids));
```

Comment: if you don't want the unique count you just can do `count($array)`

Answer (score 1):

If you need just a total count of objects, then `count()` does that, as pointed out by comment.

If you specifically need to count or otherwise access `user_id` properties specifically (for example not object have ID) it's convenient to do that with `array_column()`:

```php
$user_ids = [
    (object) [ 'user_id' => 1 ],
    (object) [ 'user_id' => 2 ],
    (object) [],
];

var_dump( count( $user_ids ) ); // 3
var_dump( count( array_column( $user_ids, 'user_id' ) ) ); // 2
```